# Unable to fetch data from server? JSON parsing result

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to parse JSON from http://dev.onlinedominosid.com/newApi/Promotions?region=JKT

I created activity_main.xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"    android:background="#F1F1F1"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and created listview (row.xml) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/promotion_saja"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_promotion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail_country"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/promotion_saja"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/promotion_saja"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_end"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date_start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date_start"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

after that I created promotion class like this:

```
public class Promotions {

private String name;
private String description;
private String date_start;
private String date_end;
private String image;

public Promotions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Promotions(String name, String description, String date_start, String date_end, String image) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.date_start = date_start;
    this.date_end = date_end;
    this.image = image;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDate_start() {
    return date_start;
}

public void setDate_start(String date_start) {
    this.date_start = date_start;
}

public String getDate_end() {
    return date_end;
}

public void setDate_end(String date_end) {
    this.date_end = date_end;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

then I created promotion adapter like this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PromotionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Promotions> {
ArrayList<Promotions> promoList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public PromotionAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Promotions> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    promoList = objects;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // convert view = design
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_promotion);
        holder.Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.Description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.Date_start = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_start);
        holder.Date_end = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_end);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(promoList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.Name.setText(promoList.get(position).getName());
    holder.Description.setText(promoList.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.Date_start.setText("Start: " + promoList.get(position).getDate_start());
    holder.Date_end.setText("End: " + promoList.get(position).getDate_end());
    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView Name;
    public TextView Description;
    public TextView Date_start;
    public TextView Date_end;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
}
```

I called the adapter in MainActivity like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Promotions> promoList;

PromotionAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    promoList = new ArrayList<Promotions>();
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://dev.onlinedominosid.com/newApi/Promotions?region=JKT");

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), promoList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}


class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONArray jsono = new JSONArray(data);

                for(int i=0;i<jsono.length();i++){
                    //HashMap<String, String> promo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject object = jsono.getJSONObject(i);
                    Promotions actor = new Promotions();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("value_name_en"));
                    actor.setDescription(object.getString("value_desc_en"));
                    actor.setDate_start(object.getString("value_date_start"));
                    actor.setDate_end(object.getString("value_date_end"));
                    actor.setImage(object.getString("value_thumb_en"));

                    promoList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        if(result == false){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            adapter = new PromotionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, promoList);
            ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    }
```

But get "Unable to fetch data from server", any wrong with my JSON parsing?
What should I do to correct that code (the correct code)?

Comment: Print your status in logcat.. what is it?

Comment: E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer

Comment: You add INTERNET permission in menifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>, already added before

Comment: what your status you still stuck any where?

Comment: Sam answer almost right, log data get all, but when I loop jsonobject, it is still not show.

Comment: Your JSON parsing code is almost correct..

Comment: the problem is here:for(int i=0;i<jsono.length();i++){
                    JSONObject object = jsono.getJSONObject(i);
                    Promotions actor = new Promotions();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                    actor.setDate_start(object.getString("date_start"));
                    actor.setDate_end(object.getString("date_end"));
                    actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));
                    promoList.add(actor);
                }

Comment: Tanya your Json key is not matching with your code..

Comment: object.getString("name") but "name" key is not present in your json data

Comment: there is "value_name_en" key present in json result

Comment: still unable with this: actor.setName(object.getString("value_name_en"));
      actor.setDescription(object.getString("value_desc_en"));
      actor.setDate_start(object.getString("value_date_start"));
      actor.setDate_end(object.getString("value_date_end"));
      actor.setImage(object.getString("value_thumb_en"));

Comment: Do one thing print your data string in logcat. If Any Exception revert back me.

Comment: E/Data: [{"value_id":"64","coupon_code":"PODX","value_name_en":"PIZZA OF THE DAY Friday","value_name_th":"","value_name_idn":"PIZZA OF THE DAY Jumat","value_desc_en":"Get Medium Hand Tossed Extravaganza for cheaper price on every Friday.","value_desc_th":null,"value_desc_idn":"Dapatkan Medium Hand Tossed Extravaganza dengan harga lebih murah setiap hari Jumat.\u00a0","value_date_start":"2014-10-01","value_date_end":"2015-12-31",...

Comment: adapter = new PromotionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, promoList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: remove from oncreate and replace by adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in postExecute()

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   dialog.dismiss();
   if (result == false)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
  }

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.jsonparsing.PromotionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Comment: Update your code in question, check it

Comment: still Unable to fetch data from server

Comment: it works, thanks pkBhati.

Comment: Cheerss... up my comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44565426/6808152 @Sam I need your help in this error please help me Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is become slightly change in android for HttpGet etc...
You can use this code for get Json response of your Link.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new JSONAsyncTask()
            .execute("http://dev.onlinedominosid.com/newApi/Promotions?region=JKT");
}

public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //New Code of Sun Microsystem for Parsing.
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection;
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            httpConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.setDoInput(true);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                InputStream iStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                Log.e("Data", result);
                //Create JSON Array of your Response.
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                //Convert into Object.Here 0 no object is define,you can 
                //use for loop for all.
                JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                //Get data using Key Value.
                Log.e("ValueId", json.getString("value_id"));
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

and dont forget to add permission of internet here

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I try to loop jsonobject but still same : for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
      //HashMap<String, String> promo = new HashMap<String, String>();
      JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      Promotions actor = new Promotions();

      actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
      actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
      actor.setDate_start(object.getString("date_start"));
      actor.setDate_end(object.getString("date_end"));
      actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

      promoList.add(actor);
     }

Comment: There is only one object in your json array there for JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0); works good here and you can see logcat there is log of json data and ValueId as well. First of all you have to check response then check your HashMap there.

Comment: JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
     Promotions actor = new Promotions();

     actor.setName(object.getString("value_name_en"));
     actor.setDescription(object.getString("value_desc_en"));
     actor.setDate_start(object.getString("value_date_start"));
     actor.setDate_end(object.getString("value_date_end"));

     promoList.add(actor);

Comment: Whenever i put log of Log.e("value_name_en", json.getString("value_name_en"));
     Log.e("value_desc_en", json.getString("value_desc_en"));
     Log.e("value_date_start",
       json.getString("value_date_start"));
     Log.e("value_date_end", json.getString("value_date_end")); then i got all values in Logcat.There is problem in your Adapter there.

Comment: Hi i am edit your code. You can download your code from http://www.4shared.com/rar/6S05ttrDba/Test.html....I works good..